# Stm32 function in "Standard Library"

Tags: c, stm32, standard-library

I have this function and this is "HAL" library:

```
void ENC28_writeBuf(uint16_t len, uint8_t* data)
{
    uint8_t spiData[2];
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    spiData[0] = ENC28_WRITE_BUF_MEM;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spiData, 1, 100);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, data, len, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

But i want to write with Standart Perhibral Library for stm32. How can i write this function in STD ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to write the init functions of SPI,GPIO and Clock in the std library. In that case, we can not understand that which SPI1 pins you are using and which stm32 processor do you use.?

You need provide detailed information pin number, stm32 processor number. It will be enough to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a simple SPI tranfer.

The lines with `HAL_GPIO_WritePin...` handle the Chip Select pin and the 
`HAL_SPI_Transmit()` does the transfer work.

In the STD Library there are no functions to transmit complete blocks of data.
So you must use 
`void SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI_TypeDef* SPIx, uint16_t Data);` and transfer one byte after the other.

The best way to get a complete example (including setup of the interface) could be found within the library itself (STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Examples\SPI\SPI_TwoBoards\SPI_DataExchangeInterrupt)